# QGIS Exponential Notation in Raster Calculator

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, raster-calculator

I am looking to execute an equation in the QGIS raster calculator using multiple instances of exponential notation. The current format I am using is as follows:

`.00005*exp (x,y)`

Where x is the input raster and y is the exponent I am attempting to raise the raster to. I am getting the error of invalid expression, any guidance would be very helpful!

Answer (score 4):

there isn't an exp() function in Raster Calculator, but there is a power/exponentiation operator (^).

Assuming you want the equivalent of python's `pow(x,y)` function, you could try

```
.00005*("raster1@1" ^ "raster2@1")
```

where raster1 and raster2 are your layer names. The @1 means 'band1'

The same operator can be used in GRASS' `r.mapcalc` algorithm although I've not tried that myself.